# How to use core helper in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, helper

I am trying to get core helper in magento 2. In Magento 1, I was using -

```
<?php $_coreHelper = $this->helper('core');
/* @var $_coreHelper Mage_Core_Helper_Data */ ?>
```

Is there any way to use core helper in magento 2, like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the following in your template:

```
$this->helper('Path/To/Helper/Class')->customMethod();
```

But it is not a good practice, see details here: [Magento 2: proper use of helpers](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/130975/2380)