# Magento 2 - What does the AbstractHelper do, and is it required?

Tags: magento2, module, helper

All of the tutorials I'm looking at pretty much say the same thing.  To add a helper, just add the following code:

```
<?php

namespace YourName\YourModule\Helper;

class ClassName extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{

...

}
```

It seems to be required in all of the tutorials, but no one explains it.  It also seems to work exactly the same if I remove it (though, my custom module is not quite as complicated as others).

Can any experts offer some insight?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your custom class don't need to extends the Abstract helper core class.

However, the Abstract helper provides helpful methods:

- Module statuses manager - `Magento\Framework\Module\Manager`
- Logger - `Magento\Framework\Logger\Monolog`
- Http request info - `Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http`
- Url - `Magento\Framework\Url`.
- Library for working with HTTP headers - `Magento\Framework\HTTP\Header`
- Event manager - `\Magento\Framework\Event\Manager`.
- Library for working with client ip address -`\Magento\Framework\HTTP\PhpEnvironment\RemoteAddress`.
- Cache configuration model. Provides cache configuration data to the application - `Magento\Framework\Cache\Config`.
- Base64 encoder and decoder for URLs - `Magento\Framework\Url\Encoder` and `Magento\Framework\Url\Decoder`.
- Application configuration object. Used to access configuration when application is initialized and installed - `Magento\Framework\App\Config`

If you want to use some helpful methods, your custom class should extends from the Abstract helper.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access the helper in templates using `$block->helper(HelperClassName::class)`, Magento will only allow it if the class extends `AbstractHelper`.

But this is not a recommended practice anyways, see: [Magento 2: proper use of helpers](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/130975/magento-2-proper-use-of-helpers)